# How do I name a division operation in a TensorFlow graph?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am writing a language model in TensorFlow, following the example in `ptb_word_lm.py`. I calculate the batch cost like so:

```py
    loss = tf.nn.seq2seq.sequence_loss_by_example([logits],
                                                  [tf.reshape(y, [-1])],
                                                  [tf.ones([batch_size * time_steps])],
                                                  name="loss")
    cost = tf.reduce_sum(loss) / batch_size
```

I would like to attach a name to the cost node in the graph so that I can visualize and do a scalar summary of it in TensorBoard. However, I cannot figure how to attach a name to the `/` infix operator. I'm thinking I have to do something like

```py
  cost = tf.DivisionOperator(cost, batch_size, name="cost")
```

but the exact syntax eludes me.

Comment: I'm not familiar with TensorFlow, but Googling `tensorflow division` shows that [`tf.div`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/math_ops.html#div), [`tf.truediv`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/math_ops.html#truediv), and [`tf.floordiv`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/math_ops.html#floordiv) all take a `name` argument. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks. I don't know how I overlooked that. You should propose that an an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`tf.div`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/math_ops.html#div), [`tf.truediv`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/math_ops.html#truediv), and [`tf.floordiv`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/math_ops.html#floordiv) all take a `name` argument. Depending on which division operator you want, one of those is probably what you're looking for.